# BSFC diagram in Mathematica

Tags: plotting

I want to make BSFC (Brake specific fuel consumption) diagram using Mathematica. My data that I use looks like this:

```
{1000, 0.639325, 774.659},
{1000, 5.65459, 369.338},
{1000, 5.75237, 368.096},
{1000, 5.83255, 366.319},
{1000, 5.86222, 365.489},
{1000, 5.88007, 365.057},
{1000, 5.89071, 365.384},
{1000, 5.89502, 365.117},
{1000, 5.89641, 365.162},
{1000, 5.89945, 365.158},
{1000, 6.72429, 355.331},
{1500, 0.728373, 634.035},
{1500, 5.97937, 337.579},
{1500, 7.92457, 320.562},
{1500, 9.18001, 313.034},
{1500, 10.2738, 308.161},
{1500, 11.1701, 305.165},
{1500, 11.9894, 302.732},
{1500, 12.7667, 300.155},
{1500, 13.5503, 298.314},
{1500, 14.3515, 296.652},
{1500, 15.172, 295.306},
{2000, 0.887087, 752.58},
{2000, 5.83166, 327.569},
{2000, 8.68958, 306.313},
{2000, 12.0656, 292.697},
{2000, 13.5976, 288.803},
{2000, 14.7829, 286.45},
{2000, 15.8161, 284.848},
{2000, 16.7889, 283.565},
{2000, 17.7299, 282.454},
{2000, 18.6714, 281.062},
{2000, 19.5929, 280.534},
{2500, 0.905921, 734.644},
{2500, 6.07029, 320.248},
{2500, 9.03302, 299.76},
{2500, 11.9699, 287.525},
{2500, 13.7954, 283.194},
{2500, 15.0118, 280.787},
{2500, 16.0397, 279.774},
{2500, 17.0133, 277.828},
{2500, 17.9567, 277.413},
{2500, 18.8812, 276.177},
{2500, 19.7997, 275.502},
{3000, 0.869656, 766.022},
{3000, 5.4832, 327.211},
{3000, 9.22216, 298.177},
{3000, 11.8693, 286.65},
{3000, 14.1377, 280.48},
{3000, 15.5497, 277.963},
{3000, 16.6956, 276.421},
{3000, 17.7136, 275.736},
{3000, 18.7074, 274.539},
{3000, 19.6701, 274.155},
{3000, 20.6324, 273.386},
{3500, 0.83591, 784.293},
{3500, 5.21733, 331.076},
{3500, 8.17716, 302.171},
{3500, 11.0182, 287.206},
{3500, 13.529, 279.185},
{3500, 14.9962, 276.756},
{3500, 16.1424, 275.014},
{3500, 17.1723, 274.338},
{3500, 18.1489, 273.617},
{3500, 19.1012, 272.991},
{3500, 20.0356, 272.111},
{4000, 0.766177, 854.202},
{4000, 4.92696, 341.376},
{4000, 7.37583, 310.322},
{4000, 10.554, 290.246},
{4000, 13.456, 280.368},
{4000, 15.0526, 277.134},
{4000, 16.2431, 275.098},
{4000, 17.2361, 274.344},
{4000, 18.1685, 273.591},
{4000, 19.0605, 273.328},
{4000, 19.9594, 272.622},
{4500, 0.711111, 919.686},
{4500, 4.55488, 353.966},
{4500, 6.4978, 321.128},
{4500, 9.93283, 293.796},
{4500, 13.293, 280.785},
{4500, 15.1006, 277.118},
{4500, 16.3688, 275.139},
{4500, 17.4169, 274.153},
{4500, 18.3698, 273.51},
{4500, 19.2793, 273.169},
{4500, 20.1683, 272.666},
{5000, 0.593298, 860.82},
{5000, 3.85261, 376.374},
{5000, 5.64961, 333.973},
{5000, 9.0714, 299.105},
{5000, 12.5738, 282.599},
{5000, 14.4273, 278.213},
{5000, 15.6796, 276.268},
{5000, 16.6785, 275.249},
{5000, 17.5949, 274.464},
{5000, 18.4624, 273.784},
{5000, 19.2818, 273.56},
{5500, 0.48766, 1264.44},
{5500, 2.93188, 418.139},
{5500, 4.92078, 348.884},
{5500, 8.12792, 305.7},
{5500, 11.5233, 286.594},
{5500, 13.3493, 281.482},
{5500, 14.5852, 278.962},
{5500, 15.5352, 278.01},
{5500, 16.3893, 277.272},
{5500, 17.1737, 277.065},
{5500, 17.9394, 276.259},
{6000, 0.503867, 1272.45},
{6000, 2.08403, 498.33},
{6000, 3.83483, 384.299},
{6000, 5.29642, 335.706},
{6000, 8.35346, 299.419},
{6000, 10.1205, 290.077},
{6000, 12.0531, 284.987},
{6000, 13.0102, 283.253},
{6000, 13.8512, 282.167},
{6000, 14.6378, 281.477},
{6000, 15.3922, 280.73},
{6500, 0.474989, 1390.29},
{6500, 1.60012, 598.519},
{6500, 3.18619, 427.004},
{6500, 3.84891, 370.409},
{6500, 6.91506, 312.63},
{6500, 8.85075, 297.857},
{6500, 8.63417, 296.341},
{6500, 9.71903, 292.11},
{6500, 10.6736, 289.73},
{6500, 11.5606, 287.949},
{6500, 12.3816, 287.043}
```

where first column is RPM, secon column is BMEP (Mean effective pressure) and last column is BSFC. Here's link to .txt [file](http://www.filedropper.com/book1_4).

I use `ListContourPlot` and result I get looks like this:

[image: BSFC]

Why do I get "blank space" at the bottom of diagram? Here's the full code I use:

`ListContourPlot[data, ImageSize -> Large, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 ContourLabels -> All, InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
 ColorFunction -> "LakeColors"]`

Comment: Have you tried `PlotRange->All`

Comment: Vist the Help Center and examine how to  improve formatting when you ask a question to make it more readable.

Comment: Ule could you please edit the question to include data in format its interpreted by Mathematica. Currently, the data you've presented is not very useful. I doubt anyone will bother formatting it into an appropriate format

Comment: It worked! I don't know how did I missed that, big thanks!

Comment: Next time, please you do it.  [(Editing)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help),
[(Formatting)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Greetings! To make the most of Mma.SE please **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimum** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: I aplogize for bad format - first time posting a question. I will improve my writing skills before posting next question.

Comment: Your question may be put [on-hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) as it seems to be [off-topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), i.e it arises from a simple mistake and is unlikely to help any future visitors as it is easily found in the documentation. Don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your future [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) are welcome. Learn about [common pitfalls here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/10397).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code:**

```
 ListContourPlot[data, ImageSize -> Large, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
     ContourLabels -> All, InterpolationOrder -> 3, PlotRange -> All, 
     ColorFunction -> "LakeColors"]
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

**Credits:**

@ *egwene sedai*